# Puiseux Series?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, power-series

WolframAlpha says that $$\sqrt{x^2-1}$$ expanded in Puiseux series near 1 is $\sqrt 2 \sqrt{x-1}$.

I don't know what a Puiseux series is; I have searched on the net but I haven't understood much... can you briefly explain it to me and how I can obtain this result?

Comment: There must be a typo in what you wrote... Also, you'd need to clarify _where_ (a base point) you were expanding near. I suspect it's "near $1$", but what you've written is just the first-order term there, since the value of $\sqrt{x+1}$ there is that $\sqrt{2}$. Check your source? Clarify?

Comment: From [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sqrt%5Bx%5E2-1%5D&t=crmtb01), this appears to be at $x=1$.

Comment: More terms to clarify: $$\sqrt{x^2-1} = \sqrt {2} (x-1)^{1/2} +\frac{1}{4}\,\sqrt {2} \left( x-1 \right) ^{3/2}-\frac{1}{32}\,
\sqrt {2} \left( x-1 \right) ^{5/2}+{\frac {\sqrt {2} \left( x-1
 \right) ^{7/2}}{128}}-{\frac {5\,\sqrt {2} \left( x-1 \right) ^{9/2}
}{2048}}+{\frac {7\,\sqrt {2} \left( x-1 \right) ^{11/2}}{8192}}+
\ldots $$

Comment: @paulgarrett yes, it is near 1. I have edited the question. Where is the typo?

Comment: @RobertIsrael It's not so clear for me... if you can help me, I'll be grateful..

Comment: @sunrise: Rewrite $\sqrt{x^2-1}=\sqrt{(x-1)(x+1)}=\sqrt{x+1}\sqrt{x-1}$. By continuity, when $x\to 1$ you have $\sqrt{x+1} = \sqrt{2} + o(1)$, so $\sqrt{x^2-1} = \sqrt{2}\sqrt{x-1} + o\left(\sqrt{x-1}\right)$. (You don't actually need Puiseux series for the first term.)

Comment: @ClementC. Thanks Clement! If you explain me how I can obtain the second term, I'll try to understand the entire mechanism... Many thanks again!

Comment: The typo was that you had just a single term, instead of an infinite series. @RobertIsrael's fuller expansion in his comment and answer shows the further terms.

Comment: @sunrise: see my answer (I am not very familiar with Puiseux series, but it turns out in this case the use of Taylor series is enough to get exactly the same expansion quite straightforwardly.)

Answer (score 19):

A Puiseux series about $x=a$ is similar to a Taylor (or more generally Laurent) series, but allowing fractional powers of $x-a$ rather than just integer powers.

I won't try to explain the whole theory, but here's a useful piece.
For simplicity, let's say the base point is $0$ (we can always arrange this by translation).  If for some positive integer $k$, a suitable branch of $f(w^k)$ is analytic in a neighbourhood of $w=0$, then we can write
$$f(w^k) = \sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j w^j$$
and then taking $w = z^{1/k}$ (for a suitable branch of this), we have the Puiseux series
$$ f(z) = \sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j z^{j/k} $$

In the case at hand, consider $f(\zeta) = \sqrt{(1+\zeta)^2 - 1} = \sqrt{2\zeta + \zeta^2}$ (I'm translating $z$ to $1+\zeta$ so the base point $z=1$ becomes $\zeta=0$).  This is not analytic at $\zeta=0$, but (for a suitable branch of the square root) $f(w^2) = w \sqrt{2 + w^2}$ is, and in fact

$$ f(w^2) = \sqrt{2} \sum_{j=0}^\infty {1/2 \choose j} 2^{-j} w^{2j+1}$$
so that
$$ f(\zeta) = \sqrt{2} \sum_{j=0}^\infty {1/2 \choose j} 2^{-j} \zeta^{(2j+1)/2} $$
i.e. (translating back)
$$ \sqrt{z^2 - 1} = \sqrt{2} \sum_{j=0}^\infty {1/2 \choose j} 2^{-j} (z-1)^{(2j+1)/2}$$

Answer (score 7):

If you are familiar with Taylor series, in this case you easily can get the same expansion "for free," without having to sweat too much. Set $y=x-1$, so that you are looking at 
$$
\sqrt{x^2-1} = \sqrt{(x+1)(x-1)} = \sqrt{(y+2)y} = \sqrt{2y}\sqrt{1+\frac{y}{2}}
$$
when $y\to 0$ (i.e., $x\to 1$). Recalling the Taylor expansion of $t\mapsto \sqrt{1+t}$ around $0$, you get
$$
\sqrt{1+\frac{y}{2}} = 1+\frac{y}{4}-\frac{y^2}{32} + o(y^3)
$$
(I only went to order $3$, but you can go much further) so that
$$\begin{align}
\sqrt{x^2-1} &= \sqrt{2y}\left(1+\frac{y}{4}-\frac{y^2}{32} + o(y^3)\right) = \sqrt{2y}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}y^{3/2}-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{32}y^{5/2} + o\!\left(y^{7/2}\right) \\ 
&=\sqrt{2}\sqrt{x-1}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}(x-1)^{3/2}-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{32}(x-1)^{5/2} + o\!\left((x-1)^{7/2}\right).
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

For understand more about Puiseux Series, you can consult **[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puiseux_series)** or this lectures notes of Commutative Algebra and Algebraic Geometry by **[Franz Winkler](http://www.risc.jku.at/education/courses/ss2012/caag/)**, chapter 9.